# Visual studio platform toolset vs Windows SDK

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, platform-tools

Why does Microsoft visual studio has different configuration properties for settings 'Windows SDK' and 'platform toolset' in same project?
I have the understanding that every windows SDK provides new/different version of platform toolset.
So how does it make sense to specify platform toolset of say Windows 10 SDK and at the same time setting the SDK option to say Windows 8.1 SDK in the same project?

Very confusing.

Comment: See the official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/general-property-page-project?view=vs-2019). Basically, the toolset is what you build *with* (compiler, linker, C/C++ libraries), while the SDK is what you build *for* (target Windows version).

Comment: How I remember it…..SDK Version: libraries and headers you want to use from …. and Tool Set: compiler and linker (version) to build your code..

Answer (score 4):

Accoding to the [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/general-property-page-project?view=vs-2019)

> For the Windows target platform, `Windows SDK Version` specifies the
>   version of the Windows SDK that your project requires.
>
> `Platform Toolset`allows the project to target a different version of
>   the Visual C++ libraries and compiler. Visual Studio C++ projects can
>   target either the default toolset installed by Visual Studio, or one
>   of the toolsets installed by several previous versions of Visual
>   Studio, including toolsets that create executables that can run on
>   Windows XP.

**"I have the understanding that every windows SDK provides new/different version of platform toolset"**

The platform toolset consists of the C++ compiler (cl.exe) and linker (link.exe), along with the C/C++ standard libraries. Platform Toolset is related to visual studio version. For example :

Visual Studio 2015: v140

Visual Studio 2017: v141

Visual Studio 2019: v142

Windows SDK is related to windows version. For example:

Windows SDK（10.0.18362.0）:Windows 10, version 1903

Windows SDK(8.1): Windows 7 or Windows Vista
[image]

Comment: Thanks. So does it mean that if I select windows 10 SDK, then the executable won't run on WinXP, Win8.1 etc?   If I take a scenario where I used toolset of VS2017 and Windows 8.1 SDK, then can the executable directly run on Win8.1 OR will it require something else as well on Win8.1 because I used latest toolset?

Comment: @J. Snow ,Windows SDK is backward compatible.If you choose Windows 10 SDK, then the executable file can run on win10, win8.1, win7 and other operating systems.If you want to configuring programs for Windows XP,I suggest you could refer to the [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/configuring-programs-for-windows-xp?view=vs-2019).If you want to configuring programs for Windows 8.1,you just need to choose win8.1sdk or  latest sdk.

Comment: There is also third confusing part - MSVC Toolset (of variable versions). Could you extend your answer with explanation of its relation too?